# What are good ways to represent "requirements" and "cannot-have" connections?

Tags: design, graph

In the context of creating an ecosystem, the graph below reveals information about it's behavior.

- Dot : A node with the entity's name. There's a tree, grass, a fern, etc.
- Blue arrow : A requirement. The tree requires grass and high altitude.
- Red line : Cannot co-exist with. Grass cannot co-exist with stone.

[image: Graph]

This may look like a nice way to represent such problem, but it quickly becomes painful when more entities are into account.

[image: Bigger graph]

I'm looking for an alternative way to represent these entities on a much larger scale.

So what are some good ways to represent this rule engine on a bigger scale?

Comment: What are the other alternatives for this kind of problem? What other ways can I represent these "requirements" and "cannot-have"? I'm looking for ways that are simple on a bigger scale.

Comment: So you're looking for help on how to build a rules engine of some kind, then?

Comment: Yes, I need a graphical representation to do better design and balancing.

Comment: To be clear, is that "Yes, I'm building a rules engine," or "No, I need a better graphical representation?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes I am building a rule engine and I need a better graphical representation of this rule engine in order to balance it.